# Ternary Operator with three options

Tags: php, ternary-operator, ternary

I'm trying to make a ternary operator that says:

- If the button is `== red-btn` place `red-btn` in the a class if it is not check
- If the button is `== white-btn` place `white-btn` in the a class if it is not check
- If the button is `== grey-btn` place `grey-btn` in the a class if it is not check
- If the button is `== red-btn` place `red-btn` etc. etc.

So it checks for one of three options that the user has chosen from my Custom Field Suite dropdown choice that outputs `red-btn, white-btn or grey-btn` depending on the users selection.

**This is my code:**

```
printf("<a class=\"%s\"href=\"%s\">%s</a></div>\n", $colour=="red-btn"?"red-btn": $colour=="white-btn"?"white-btn\": $colour=="grey-btn"?"grey-btn"", $button_link_url, $button_title);
```

I know this is wrong but need help writing it out correctly.

Comment: A ternary operator **can't** have three choices, since the condition only returns `true` or `false`. Use a `switch` or an `if elseif else` construct.

Comment: Maybe I've titled this wrong. I want it to check if it is "red-btn" if it is place that as the a class. If it is not check if it is white-btn if it is place that as the a class. If its not check if it is grey-btn... etc etc

Comment: Still can't use a ternary operator for anything more than 2 results.  As Daan commented above, use a switch, or a if-elseif-else structure - assign the result to a common-named variable which you put in your `printf`.

Comment: @qirel If I do an if-elseif-else function how do I check if $colour is a certain string? Rather than checking if $colour is $someothervariable

Comment: Isn't `$color` exactly what you need anyway? Can't you just put that variable directly into the class? Also, in your code, you don't check for strings, you check for constants, because `$colour==red-btn` compares to the constant `red-btn`, not the string (use quotes).

Comment: @qirel I tried this:
printf("<a class=\"%s\"href=\"%s\">%s</a></div>\n", $colour , $button_link_url, $button_title);

But it doesnt work

Comment: @qirel I've changed it to this but its still returning an error:

printf("<a class=\"%s\"href=\"%s\">%s</a></div>\n", $colour=="red-btn"?"red-btn": $colour=="white-btn"?"white-btn\": $colour=="grey-btn"?"grey-btn"", $button_link_url, $button_title);

Comment: `var_dump($color);` - what is it? You commented that you got an "array"? @AaronDavis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($buttons as $button){
                        //var_dump($button);
                        $button_title = $button['button_title'];
                        $button_link_url = $button['button_link_url'];
                        $colour = $button['colour'];

                        reset($colour);
                        $first_colour = key($colour);

                        var_dump($first_colour);
                        printf("<a class='%s' href='%s'>%s</a>\n",
                            ($first_colour=="Red")?"red-btn":(
                                ($first_colour=="White")?"white-btn":(
                                    ($first_colour=="Grey")?"grey-btn":""
                                )
                            ),
                            $button_link_url,
                            $button_title
                        );
                    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need some more brackets. Something like this

```
printf("<a class=\"%s\" href=\"%s\">%s</a></div>\n",
    ($colour=="red-btn")?"red-btn":(
        ($colour=="white-btn")?"white-btn":(
            ($colour=="grey-btn")?"grey-btn":""
        )
    ),
    $button_link_url,
    $button_title
);
```

Comment: Aside, although it's possible to nest ternarys like this, there might be a nicer way to rewrite the code without using them (eg a switch block)

Comment: I've changed it to this but its not finding and placing the class in the ""

printf("<a class=\"%s\" href=\"%s\">%s</a></div>\n", $colour=="red"?"red-btn":$colour=="white"?"white-btn":$colour=="grey"?"grey-btn":"", $button_link_url, $button_title);

I don't know how to do switch blocks I'm afraid

Comment: I've edited to add a space between the class attribute and the href attribute, which might be your problem

Comment: This still doesn't add anything to the class for some reason :(

Comment: We've discovered that `$colour` is an array, not a string, so the whole basis of this code is nonsense. It's never going to match any of the options, so will put `""` in because that's the fall-back.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same using 3 conditions, so this is what I did:

```
btn-color == 'btn-white' ? "btn-white" : btn-color == 'btn-red' ? "btn-red" : "btn-grey"
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's another option that doesn't answer the stated question (about ternary operators), but might answer the underlying question about putting the right class in the html

```
printf("<a class='%s' href='%s'>%s</a></div>\n",
    $colour,
    $button_link_url,
    $button_title
);
```

Comment: This is putting a class in the "" but its putting the class "array" in. I'm not too sure what this means. Does it mean its trying to add the whole array as a class?

Comment: It means that `$colour` is an array, not a string.

Comment: How do I pull the colour out of that array? I know its with [ ] but I don't know where I need to put them

Comment: I have no idea what is in the array. At some point, you're going to need to do some actual debugging. Start with `var_dump($colour)`.